Proving $3\nmid y$ given $y^2=x^3-9$ and $y$ is even
Given $y^2=x^3-9$ and $y$ is even. Prove that $3\nmid y$.
Attempt:
Assume towards a contradiction that $3\mid y$, then
$$y\equiv0\pmod3,\quad y^2+9\equiv0\pmod3,\quad x^3\equiv0\pmod3,\quad x\equiv0\pmod3.$$
Not sure how to get to the desired result.

Hint: $,x^3 = 9n,\Rightarrow, 3\mid n\ \ $

You've made a good start. With $y \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $y = 3a$ for some integer $a$. Also, as you've shown, $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, so $x = 3b$ for some integer $b$. We then get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
y^2 & = x^3 - 9 \\
(3a)^2 & = (3b)^3 - 9 \\
9a^2 & = 27b^3 - 9 \\
a^2 & = 3b^3 - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
This shows that $a^2 \equiv 2\pmod{3}$. However, all integral squares are congruent to only either $0$ or $1$ modulo $3$. This contradiction shows that the original assumption of $y \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ must be wrong, so $3$ doesn't divide $y$.
Note this is true for all integers $y$, not only even ones.

Continuing that chain of thought, let $y = 3k$ and $x = 3m$.
We get $9k^2 = 27m^3 - 9 \implies k^2 = 3m^3 - 1$. We know $k$ is even, so let $k = 2n$.
We get $3m^3 = 4n^2 + 1$
We can show that $3$ does not divide RHS.
If $n = 0 \bmod 3$, RHS = $1 \bmod 3$
If $n = 1 \bmod 3$, RHS = $2 \bmod 3$
If $n = -1 \bmod 3$, RHS = $2 \bmod 3$
